# Passing URL parameters back to main page from subpages using Ajax/JQuery/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

Page1.aspx has a span element "class1" which fires an Ajax request for a ".click" event, this is processed by Page2.aspx. Page2.aspx renders another span element with "class2". Clicking on "class2" fires another Ajax request defined on Page3.aspx.

The question is, how do I get Page1.aspx to pick up on the **anotherid** parameter, so I can process it?? All results are rendered back to #results.

Am I even doing this right in the first place???

**Page1.aspx (HTML):**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.class1').click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        //detect span "class2" was clicked and append to url here?
        //data: "id=" + this.id + ",anotherid=" + ???
        data: "id=" + this.id,
        url: "Page2.aspx",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
          $('#results').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><span class="class1" id="123">Click</span></div>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2.aspx (Code Behind):**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
  Response.Write("<span class=\"class2\" id="456">" + id + "</span>");
}
```

**Page2.aspx (HTML):**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.class2').click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        data: "anotherid=" + this.id,
        url: "Page3.aspx",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
          $('#results').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page3.aspx (Code Behind):**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  string tags = Request.QueryString["anotherid"];
  //do something with anotherid.
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `Page1.aspx` is doing anything with `anotherid`.  Did you mean `Page3.aspx`?

Comment: i really cannot understand what you want, what is the exact problem/error you are facing

Comment: Hi, sorry it's not clear. I'm not getting an error message as I don't know how to do it in the first place. What I want to do is pass "anotherid" back to Page1.aspx for processing... how do I detect that span "class2" was clicked from Page1.aspx? I have added a comment line in my code to make things clearer...

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PageX.aspx?anotherid=" + $(this).attr("id"),
        success: function (data) {
          $('#results').html(data.text());
        }
      });
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: Any chance you could explain why it might be helpful, for those finding this post in the future?